# Reading a map file from console, then making it into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, file

[The map txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nouyx.png)I need to make a random map in a txt file, then get it into the code and someway translate it into a 2d array. The "map" is like a Pac-Man map, where walls are "*" and the path where the player can move is " ". The problem I am having is reading the file and then getting into the 2d array. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which is the part you are having trouble in? Generating the map in txt file or reading the file or converting what is read into array?

Comment: Don't have to generate the map. You just type it before hand. So I am having trouble in the last two stages you've said, reading the file and converting to the array!

Comment: do you have some criteria or any approach to read and convert to 2d array will be enough?

Comment: You should update your post with an example of the txt map.

Comment: @walidbarakat Just that you have to read it through the console. I mean name.exe < map.txt . Nothing more than that!

Answer (score 0):

with C++ you can use **std::ifstream input("here you pass the file name")** and then you can `for( std::string line; getline( input, line ); ) { here you can iterate over the line (row) and make your 2d array }`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    std::cout << "Require 1 map.txt as input" << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }
  std::vector<char> v;
  char ch;
  std::fstream fin(argv[1], std::fstream::in);
  unsigned nonNewLine = 0;
  unsigned row = 1; // assuming last row has no new line
  while (fin >> std::noskipws >> ch) {
      if (ch == '\n') ++row;
      else ++nonNewLine;
      v.push_back(ch);
  }
  unsigned col = (row + nonNewLine) / row;
  // vector is 1d array which you can use as a 2d array by v[i * col + j]

  // but if you really need 2d array
  char** p = new char*[row];
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
    p[i] = new char[col];
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
      p[i][j] = v[i * col + j];
    }
  }
  // use p[i][j]

  // clean up
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
    delete[] p[i];
  }
  delete[] p;

  return 0;
}
```